# Ansible AWS AutoScale group keep adding the desire server instead of update the correct number

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am using `Ansible` latest version `2.0.1.0`

I try to create new AWS autoscale config like this

```
- name: Update ASG with new LC and replace all instances
  ec2_asg:
    name: "{{ asg_name }}"
    launch_config_name: "{{ lc_name }}-{{ timestamp }}"
    health_check_period: 300
    health_check_type: ELB
    min_size: 1
    max_size: 5
    desired_capacity: 1
    region: "{{ aws_region }}"
    load_balancers: "{{ lb_name }}"
    vpc_zone_identifier: "{{ vpc_zones }}"
    tags:
      - Name: "{{ asg_name }}"
      - Environment: "{{ stack_env }}"
    replace_all_instances: yes
```

It creates the autoscale group, but when I rerun the playbook the number of `min/max/desired` instances in AWS autoscale group will be sum up to `2/5/6`. Basically it will sum up the config inside AWS and the setting inside playbook.

The documentation of `ec2_asg` said it will replace/update the number inside the config. Did I miss something here?

Thank you!

### Update

Because I am using `replace_all_instances` then Ansible will rolling replace all running instances in the ASG. But sometimes it got timeout when waiting new instance up then the playbook exit. So the number of `min/max/desire` number of instances in ASG was not updated to correct number.

Comment: It changed to `2/5/6` immediately after running the playbook? Did you check after 5 or 10 mins?

Comment: @helloV oh I got it. Because I am using `replace_all_instances` so it will rolling replace old instances in the autoscale group. In my case I sometime my playbook return timeout when waiting new instance up & join the ELB, so it exit. Then the asg is not change back to old number. I updated my question with detail.